# Is there a way to Dockerize my MySQL DB with express and host that container on digital ocean .. etc?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, express

I want to use Docker to make a container that contains a MySQL DB with Express to expose into certain ports for example `8080` so I can fetch that using React for the view.

Right now I made simple server with express that fetches the data from a MySQL database and displays it on 'localhost:8000/posts' (posts is where i am using SQL Query to select everything from the table.

This is a index.ts file:

```js
//Main File
import express from "express";
import { connection } from "./db-connect";
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

var cors = require("cors");
/*
cors was installed so I could get the data
and display it to react, otherwise I was getting an error
in the console.
*/

app.use(cors());

app.listen(80, function() {
  console.log("CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Go to /posts to see the Data");
});

app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM blog.posts", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else {
      return res.json(result);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

So I have a database named `blog` with table called `posts`
With this I am getting an array with data as an object which is I wanted.

What I wanted to learn is Dockerize this into a container. With MySQL that has `blog` database with `posts` table that contains id, title, body and user.

After I'd like to host the Docker that contains the db and deploy it to digitalocean or similar service.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for this.

You'd then have a .yml file that looks something like this:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
    # Use this to connect to your dockerized mysql container
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Use this port in your express app
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  my-db:
```

Then you need to dockerize your express app and include it in the *docker-compose.yml* file. [Here](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) is a guide on how to dockerize a node.js app such as yours.

Once you succeeded to connect the two containers in docker-compose, deploying it on a Digital Ocean server is just as easy as installing Docker-Compose on the server (if it's not already installed), copying your code to the server and running *docker-compose up --build*.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your kind response! I am going to look into it and learn more, to be honest I am still learning Dockers but with experience I think I can get there.

Comment: Shared link is dead :(